# Webpack compiling ES6 into module

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, vue.js

I am trying to compile ES6 to a file using Webpack and can't figure out why the code is not usable as it is.

> Side note : This is meant to be a plugin for VueJS

I start with a simple file that exports a single function such as

```
exports.install = () => {
  ...
}
```

Webpack uses `babel-loader` and `babel-preset-es2015` to compile it.

You may find webpack config, source and compiled files in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kartsims/dab115cc1755a503b79431eaff829963).

My problem is the result is not "requirable" in my Vue app... It has some weird stuff around the core needed `exports.install` statement. When I remove all this stuff and leave just `exports.install = ...` it is OK, otherwise I just don't get anything out of it.

I am using it in another app built with webpack, through an `import` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without an [`output.libraryTarget`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget) option, webpack will generate a bundle you can include via a `<script>` tag, **but not `import`**. I think this is what you're seeing.

If you want to `import` (or `require`) the result of your webpack build, you should set `libraryTarget` to `commonjs2`

```
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
  },
```

With this `libraryTarget` configuration, the webpack output will look like `module.exports = /* ... the "weird stuff" */`, so when you import it, you'll get the exported function you expect.

---

If all you're doing is compiling a single file or set of files that will be imported in another webpack build, you might consider not using webpack at all, and instead using the [Babel CLI](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) directly. In your Gist, you're not getting anything from webpack other than wrapping your module in some extra webpack bootstrap code.

Comment: THANK YOU ! I tried using Babel CLI directly but I am not sure how I can compile multiple files in one with it... If you could give me a hint that would be great.